# Capture browser cached data dropdown onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm having some problems adding a dropdownlist with ajax and stuff using jQuery. When you click or you type on the input text a method creating the jQuery dropdownlist will be called. However if you already submitted this form, when you type you get the typical browser simple dropdown with previous submitted data. I'm having a hard time figuring what event do trigger clicking in that dropdownlist element.

Comment: @VisioN just add a normal <input type="text" id="someId"> in a form, submit some data, and return to the form. When you type the first character of the data you submitted, you will get this dropdownlist, then click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
autocomplete="off"
```

attribute to your input fields, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="myField" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get rid of it, i'm trying to capture an event to know when I click it :/

Comment: You can't. It browser specific. And you can't acces to that popup. You need to write your own.